# package com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk not found

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Dataflow Java code stopped compiling/running when executed from Maven:

```
[ERROR] symbol:   class Pipeline
[ERROR] location: package com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk
[ERROR] ... package com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io does not exist
[ERROR] ... package com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options does not exist
[ERROR] ... package com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pom.xml probably includes a line such as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
  <version>[1.6.0, 2.0.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

This pulls in a breaking change to 2.0-beta where Google Dataflow package names have gotten changed to org.apache.beam.

For now, change the pom.xml setting to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
  <version>[1.6.0, 1.9.9)</version>
</dependency>
```

And when you are ready, follow the instructions in

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2

to update your Java code.  It's not just changing package names. Your runner names will change, and DoFns will need a @ProcessElement annotation also, among other changes.